# How to determine depth of root directory subdirectories PHP

Tags: php, directory, glob, subdirectory

I'm using glob recursion to find all directories with index.php files in them. What I am trying to do is figure out if the depth goes beyond a certain level.

Example:
root folder: `/`

subdirectory of root: `./subdirectory/`

subdirectory of subdirectory: `./dubdirectory/subdirectory/`

Level 0 would be the root folder.

Level 1 would be the subdirectory.

Level 2 would be the subdirectory of the subdirectory.

How can I determine if the depth goes to as far as level 2 or beyond?

pseudo code example:

```
if ($subdirectory_depth >= 2) {
    //do something;
}
```

Here is my glob script

```
if ( ! function_exists('glob_recursive'))
{
    function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0 )
    {
        $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
        foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir)
        {
            if (preg_match('#/(?:cgi-bin|css|images|includes|test)#', $dir)) continue; // exclude these directories

            $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
        }
        return $files;
    }
}

$dirlist = glob_recursive( $dir_structure.'*index.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just count the number of '/'?

E.g.

```
<?
if ( ! function_exists('glob_recursive'))
{
    function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0 )
    {
        $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
        foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir)
        {
            if (preg_match('#/(?:cgi-bin|css|images|includes|test)#', $dir)) continue; // exclude these directories

            $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
        }
        return $files;
    }
}

$dirlist = glob_recursive( '/home/storage/e/63/25/phpsandbox/ToBeDeleted/2015/may/'.'*index.php' );
$maxdept = 10;
foreach($dirlist as $filepath) {
    $dept = substr_count($filepath, '/');
    echo '<br>'.$filepath.' Dept: '.$dept;
    if($dept > $maxdept) {
        echo ' (Deeper than '.$maxdept.')';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: counting the `/` is one of the ideas I have. Just trying to figure out the right way to do it. I'll test your code and get back.